# 1920s wood flooring type

Tags: flooring, kitchens, tongue-and-groove

I have a 1928 pacific northwest house. There is some kind of tongue and groove flooring under the existing flooring in my kitchen but it is difficult to see what it is. It is about a 1/2 inch thick and 2 inches wide. Does anyone have any idea what it might be? I am interested in removing the existing flooring that is on top of it and refinishing it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's no way for us to tell without further information. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Look to see if sub -floor under tongue and grove.  If only 1/2 inch thick should be on top of sub-floor. And should be able to refinish. Sorry about some of the comments on site. Some think they are funny,and i try  to answer . All without bs.